# Vertical UIScrollView Infinite Scrolling in iOS app

Tags: ios, infinite-scroll

I want to add infinite scrolling feature in UIScrollView when i scroll down in it just like the one used in Facebook iOS application. Can anyone provide code/sample project performing this specific functionality?

Comment: What about redefining the content size when your scroll offset is bigger than the content size height minus a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can apply contentsize based on your needs,

  ```
  scrollviewObj.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width, height); apply height as per your need.
  ```